# How to fix the showing date in DatePicker using useState REACT-JS

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have DatePicker and i want to set the value of selected date to state

```
import DatePicker from "react-modern-calendar-datepicker";

const [currentApp, setCurrentApp] = useState({
    ceo_birthday: null,
})
```

this is the `renderCustomInputDateOfBirth` method

```
const renderCustomInputDateOfBirth = ({ ref }) => (
<input
  readOnly
  value={ currentApp.ceo_birthday }
  onChange={(e) => setCurrentApp({...currentApp, ['ceo_birthday'] : e })}
  style={{
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: "10px 10px",
    fontSize: "1rem",
    border: "1px solid #dadada",
    borderRadius: "100px",
    color: "#616161",
    outline: "none",
    backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
  }}
  className="my-custom-input-class" // a styling class
/>
```

);

this is the `DatePicker`

```
<DatePicker
    open={isOpen}
    value={currentApp.ceo_birthday}
    renderInput={renderCustomInputDay}
    calendarPopperPosition="bottom"
    onChange={
        (e) => setCurrentApp({
            ...currentApp, 
            ['ceo_birthday'] : e  })} 
    shouldHighlightWeekends
/>
```

the problem is when I select the date, the `currentApp.ceo_birthday` have the date but nothing show in input box

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have one memory reference. `ceo_birthday` does not change. Try to create a base state for your date.

`const [date, setDate] = useState(null)`